# E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pip

I am new to Linux. I have been trying to install pip in python But get this error: E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)

What is this error ? How to resolve this or is there any other way to install pip in Ubuntu?

Comment: The answer could be found here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process

Answer (score 8):

Try removing the lock file and then update the apt-get sources:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo apt-get update
```

Looks like this guy had a similar issue installing Twisted: http://www.unixmen.com/solve-error-e-get-lock-varcacheaptarchiveslock-open-11-resource-temporarily-unavailable-e-unable-lock-directory-varcacheaptarchives-debian-7/

Comment: from https://askubuntu.com/a/315791/707756 " all the answers recommend deleting the lock. That must never be done, it is always preferable to kill dpkg (which is supposed to be resilient against that kind of event), than to even think about removing its lock file (where its presence does not indicate the lock being held)."

Answer (score 4):

First make sure you don't have any other pip installation going on. If you are sure there's none, then try doing

```
sudo mv /var/cache/apt/archives/lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock.backup
```

Now try running pip installation again. If it doesn't work or something goes wrong, do:

```
sudo mv /var/cache/apt/archives/lock.backup /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

and comment here. We will think of new things to try then :)